# Can't import libsvm in jupyter notebook (ubuntu on windows)

Tags: python, jupyter-notebook, libsvm, windows-subsystem-for-linux

I am launching my jupyter notebook from my ubuntu on windows. I ran "sudo apt-get install python-libsvm" to install libsvm, and could successfully "from svmutil import *" in my ubuntu's python. However, I am unable to import it in my jupyter notebook, which states "No module named 'svmutil'".

Comment: I think it may be the python version, since my jupyter notebook runs python3. Is libsvm only available for python2?

Comment: See https://stackoverflow.com/q/53931575/6309